# How exactly does 'this' keyword assign properties to functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, properties, callback, this, prototype

I tried to recreate javascript promise, following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/globant/how-i-recreated-a-javascript-promise-from-scratch-f649931dadfe), this is the complete code from the tutorial:

```
function myPromise(callback) {

    let resolve = function(value){
        this.resolveCallback(value);
    }
    callback(resolve)

}

// .then
myPromise.prototype.then = function(resolveCallback){
    attachResolveCallback(resolveCallback);
}

const attachResolveCallback = function(resolveCallback){
  this.resolveCallback = resolveCallback;
}
```

im confused about the part that implements .then():

```
// .then
myPromise.prototype.then = function(resolveCallback){
    attachResolveCallback(resolveCallback);
}

const attachResolveCallback = function(resolveCallback){
  this.resolveCallback = resolveCallback;
}
```

Why is const attachResolveCallback needed, instead of just using this keyword in the prototype function?

So I replaced the .then part of the code with:

```
myPromise.prototype.then = function(resolveCallback){
    this.resolveCallback = resolveCallback;
}
```

But the code does not work and returns an error:

```
promise.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: this.resolveCallback is not a function
    at resolve (promise.js:4:14)
    at promise.js:25:9
```

I suspect this problem is due to usage of 'this' when assigning properties to functions, but im not sure about the specific reason here. Could someone enlighten me on this problem?

Comment: *"...following this tutorial, this is the complete code from the tutorial:"* Then I strongly urge you to put it aside and find a different tutorial. That code is **really** poor on multiple levels.

Comment: *"Why is `const attachResolveCallback` needed, instead of just using this keyword in the prototype function?"* `this` would mean something different there. Because `attachResolveCallback` is a traditional function, the value of `this` during a call to it is set by how the call is made. The way `then` makes the call in that code uses the default `this`, which is the global object in loose mode or `undefined` in strict mode (all new code should use strict mode). So that code would fail in strict mode. In loose mode, it sets `resolveCallback` as a **global**.

Comment: But seriously, again, close the tab with that tutorial in it and never open it again. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh so it's **global**! That makes more sense, yeah now it seems like that is indeed a poor tutotial :D Thanks a lot for the reply!